# A woman gets turned into a man by a makeover machine

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I remember seeing this movie between 2000 and 2008 on one of the premium TV channels like HBO or Showtime.  In the movie there is this girl that’s not entirely happy with her life.  Early in the movie she visits this one booth thing that allows you to take your appearance and alter it.  She alters it to the point where she is a guy and somewhat tall.  Something happens, like an explosion, and she ends up outside of the booth.  She quickly discovers that she’s been turned into a guy, looking exactly the way she looked in the booth thing.

The rest of the story is about her adapting to the new body, trying to figure out what to do (I don't remember a lot of the details from this part).  The movie had a foreign feel to it, maybe Swedish or something, but I’m not 100% sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [Virtual Sexuality (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164221/).

[image: DVD Cover]

Here's a part of the storyline:

> Desperate to find her perfect man Justine goes to a technology fair with her nerdy classmate Chas. It's not really her thing but is eventually persuaded to try a **virtual reality makeover machine** and discovers that she can create her perfect man even if it is only an electronic facsimile. *The power surge from a freakish accident causes a part of her psyche to be copied into her virtual perfect man and he becomes real*!